# Hadoop: Help needed while implementing a custom FileInputFormat-class

Tags: hadoop

i'm trying to implement some Map/Reduce job with hadoop for a college assignment. but at the moment i'm totally stuck while implementing a custom FileInputFormat class to get the whole content from a file into my mapper.

i took the example out of "hadoop: the definitive guide" without no changes. i can compile my source code but if i run it it will throw this exception (at the moment i use hadoop 1.0.2 on a debian 5.0)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.myorg.ExampleFileInputFormat$WholeFileInputFormat.<init>()
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getInputFormat(JobConf.java:575)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:989)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:981)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$600(JobClient.java:174)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:897)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1261)
    at org.myorg.ExampleFileInputFormat.run(ExampleFileInputFormat.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.myorg.ExampleFileInputFormat.main(ExampleFileInputFormat.java:172)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.myorg.ExampleFileInputFormat$WholeFileInputFormat.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:1985)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    ... 21 more
```

i'm kind of frustrated because i don't understand what happens and i don't find anything using web search. Maybe some of you could take a look on my source. it's kind of stripped down at the moment for the purpose of debugging.

---

```
package org.myorg;
/*
 * 
 * 
 */
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;


public class ExampleFileInputFormat extends Configured implements Tool {

     /*
      *  <generics>
      */
    public class WholeFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<NullWritable, BytesWritable> {

        @Override
        protected boolean isSplitable(FileSystem fs, Path filename) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public RecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable> getRecordReader(InputSplit split, JobConf job, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
            return new WholeFileRecordReader((FileSplit) split, job);   
        }
    }

    public class WholeFileRecordReader implements RecordReader<NullWritable, BytesWritable> {

        private FileSplit fileSplit;
        private Configuration conf;
        private boolean processed = false;

        public WholeFileRecordReader(FileSplit fileSplit, Configuration conf) throws IOException {
            this.fileSplit = fileSplit;
            this.conf = conf;
        }

        @Override
        public NullWritable createKey() {
            return NullWritable.get();
        }

        @Override
        public BytesWritable createValue() {
            return new BytesWritable();
        }

        @Override
        public long getPos() throws IOException {
            return processed ? fileSplit.getLength() : 0;
        }

        @Override
        public float getProgress() throws IOException {
            return processed ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean next(NullWritable key, BytesWritable value) throws IOException {
            if (!processed) {
                  byte[] contents = new byte[(int) fileSplit.getLength()];
                  Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
                  FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
                  FSDataInputStream in = null;
                  try {
                    in = fs.open(file);
                    IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);
                    value.set(contents, 0, contents.length);
                  } finally {
                    IOUtils.closeStream(in);
                  }
                  processed = true;
                  return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            // do nothing
        }
    }
      /* </generics> */


    /* 
     * <Task1>: 
     * */
    public static class ExampleMap extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<NullWritable, BytesWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
     private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
      private Text word = new Text();
      public void map(NullWritable key, BytesWritable value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
          output.collect(new Text("test"), one);
        }
      }
    public static class ExampleReduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
      public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
          sum += values.next().get();
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
      }
    }
    /* </Task1> */
    /*
     * <run>
     **/
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

        if (args.length != 3) {
            printUsage();
            return 1;
        }

        String useCase = args[0];
        String inputPath = args[1];
        String outputPath = args[2];

        deleteOldOutput(outputPath);        


        JobConf conf = new JobConf(ExampleFileInputFormat.class);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(outputPath));      
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(inputPath));

        /* conf: Task1 */
        if (useCase.equals("cc_p")) {
            conf.setJobName("WordCount");
            /* Output: Key:Text -> Value:Integer */
            conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);
            /* Input: Key.Text -> Value:Text */
            conf.setInputFormat(WholeFileInputFormat.class);
            conf.setMapperClass(ExampleMap.class);
            conf.setReducerClass(ExampleReduce.class);
        }
        /* default-option: Exit */
        else {
            printUsage();
            return 1;
        }

        JobClient.runJob(conf);
        return 0;
    }
    /* </run> */

    /*
     * <Main>
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new ExampleFileInputFormat(), args);
        System.exit(res);
    }
    /* </Main> */

    /* 
    * <Helper>
    */
    private void printUsage() {
        System.out.println("usage: [usecase] [input-path] [output-path]");
        return;
    }

    private void deleteOldOutput(String outputPath) throws IOException {
        // Delete the output directory if it exists already
        Path outputDir = new Path(outputPath);
        FileSystem.get(getConf()).delete(outputDir, true);
    }
    /* </Helper->   */
}
```

---

Can anyone help me out?

Greetings from Germany,
Alex

Answer (score 4):

You need to make the inner class static:

```
public static class WholeFileInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<NullWritable, BytesWritable> {
```

Otherwise Javac generats a constructor that expects a parent ExampleFileInputFormat class instance to be passed in.

Comment: indeed, that's obvious. never thought about this before. Thanks a lot. You saved my but ;-)