# Hadoop map reduce whole file input format

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to use the hadoop map reduce, but instead of mapping each line at a time in my Mapper, I would like to map a whole file at once.

So I have found these two classes
(https://code.google.com/p/hadoop-course/source/browse/HadoopSamples/src/main/java/mr/wholeFile/?r=3)
That suppose to help me do this.

And I got a compilation error that says :

> The method setInputFormat(Class) in the type
>   JobConf is not applicable for the arguments
>   (Class) Driver.java /ex2/src    line 33 Java
>   Problem

I changed my Driver class to be

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

import forma.WholeFileInputFormat;

/*
 * Driver
 * The Driver class is responsible of creating the job and commiting it.
 */
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(Driver.class);
        conf.setJobName("Get minimun for each month");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        // previous it was 
        // conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        // And it was changed it to :
        conf.setInputFormat(WholeFileInputFormat.class);

        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf,new Path("input"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,new Path("output"));

        System.out.println("Starting Job...");
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
        System.out.println("Job Done!");
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put content from [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/jBnd8mn2) to question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your wholeFileInputFormat class has correct imports.  You are using old MapReduce Api in your job Driver. I think you imported new API FileInputFormat in your WholeFileInputFormat class. If i am right, You should import **org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat** in your wholeFileInputFormat class instead of **org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat** .

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, the change did't help, because now the wholeFileInputFormat class has a compilation error, but thanks for making me realise that I am using the old version of the MapReduce api.(I thought I am using the newest one somehow, because my hadoop version is 2.6).

So I found a solution for this that use on old version of MapReduce api and now it is working.

This is the solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457700/hadoop-help-needed-while-implementing-a-custom-fileinputformat-class

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is to gzip your input file. This will make `FileInputFormat.isSplitable()` to return false.

Answer (score 1):

We too ran into something similar and had an alternative out-of-box approach.

Let say you need to process 100 large files (f1, f2,...,f100) such that you need to read one file *wholly* in the map function. So instead of using the "WholeInputFileFormat" reader approach we created equivalent 10 text files (p1, p2,...,p10) each file containing either the HDFS URL or web URL of the f1-f100 files.

Thus p1 will contain url for f1-f10, p2 will urls for f11-f20 and so on.

These new files p1 thru p10 are then used as input to mappers. Thus the mapper m1 processing file p1 will open file f1 thru f10 one at a time and process it wholly.

This approach allowed us to control the number of mappers and write more exhaustive and complex application logic in map-reduce application. E.g we could run NLP on PDF files using this approach.